# Multiplication of $p$-adic integer is injective?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Consider the group homomorphism  of $p$-adic integers
>   $$m: \Bbb Z_p \rightarrow \Bbb Z_p, (x_i) \mapsto (mx_i)$$
>   I could somehow show that this map is injective. (Which doesn't seem that right).

---

*Argument:* I claim that for any prime $q$, the multiplication is injective. Hence as composition, $m$ is too. Suppose $(qx_i)=0$. We know in $\Bbb Z$, for each $i \ge 1$, 
$$qx_{i+1}=p^{i+1}{y'}_{i+1}, {y'}_{i+1}\in \Bbb Z$$
This shows at least $$x_{i+1}=p^{i+1}y_{i+1}$$
Thence $p^i|x_i$ for all $i \ge 1$.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, your argument is correct for $q \ne p$. You need to handle the case $q=p$ separately, but it's similar.

In fact, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain so multiplication by any nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an injection.